PIxiedust 1.1.19 installed and imported properly but not working
I'm trying to use the pixie debugger in my jupyter notebook running python 3.9.
However, after successfully installing and importing pixiedust calling the cell magic %%pixie_debugger doesn't seem to run the line below.

I tried searching to make sure pixiedust is compatible with Python 3.9. I am expecting to run the cell with the %%pixie_debugger and to see a interactive GUI where I can debug the line below step by step.

That hasn't been updated since 2021 according to here. So you may be battling a lot to get it to work, see here for others saying much the same. You don't say what version or flavor of Jupyter you are using but unless it is nbclassic (JN version 6.4 or lower), I doubt it will work. Alas, there is good news though. JupyterLab has a built in visual debugger, see https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/debugger.html .

Plus, I think it needs a special kernel. (See top of answer here and linked content there.) Did you install that?
